# Поиск по асоциативному массиву, получить первое совпадение

Tags: php

Нужно найти в асоциативном массиве($userdb), массив с ключом uid(данный ключ есть во всех массивах), где к значению ключа uid присвоено значение 5465
Как это сделать? я прочитал достаточно что уже голова закипела и глаза болят ))

```
$userdb = array(
    array(
        'uid' => '100',
        'name' => 'Sandra Shush',
        'pic_square' => 'urlof100'
    ),
    array(
        'uid' => '5465',
        'name' => 'Stefanie Mcmohn',
        'pic_square' => 'urlof100'
    ),
    array(
        'uid' => '40489',
        'name' => 'Michael',
        'pic_square' => 'urlof40489'
    )
);
```

Comment: цикл напишите по массиву да проверяйте. как совпадет - вот и нашли.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно просто отфильтровать исходный массив с помощью *array_filter()*:

```
$userdb = array(
    array(
        'uid' => '100',
        'name' => 'Sandra Shush',
        'pic_square' => 'urlof100'
    ),
    array(
        'uid' => '5465',
        'name' => 'Stefanie Mcmohn',
        'pic_square' => 'urlof100'
    ),
    array(
        'uid' => '40489',
        'name' => 'Michael',
        'pic_square' => 'urlof40489'
    )
);

$need = [5465, 100];

$userdb = array_filter($userdb, function($a)use($need){
    return in_array($a['uid'], $need);
});

var_dump($userdb);
```

---

Но если нужно получить только одно (первое) совпадение, то тут лучше использовать цикл:

```
$need = 5465;

foreach ($userdb as $a) {
    if ($a['uid'] == $need) {
        $userdb = $a;
        break;
    }
}

var_dump($userdb);
```

Comment: о, а ```array_filter()```  может отфильтровать из массива несколько с разными значениями к примеру нужно не только $need = 5465; а еще и $need2 = 100

Comment: @Alexander да, я подкорректировал свой ответ.